# solr edismax search for words containing substring

Tags: solr, edismax

Using eDisMax with SOLR 5.2.1 to search for a string, when I set the `q` parameter to that string, SOLR only matches fields containing that string as a whole word.  For example,
`q=bc123` will match "aa-bc123" but not "aabc123".  If I add the `*` character before or after the phrase, than to match the search, there must be trailing and leading characters.  For example, `q=*bc123*` will match "abc123a" but will not match "bc123".

The questions is -- what query string will match words containing the search words with or without trailing/leading characters?

Please note:

1. There are multiple fields to match, which are defined using the `qf` parameter

   qf=field1^4 field2^3 field2^2 ...
2. The search may contain multiple words, eg. for `q=abc def` I want fields that contain both words containing "abc" and words containing "def", such as using `q.op=AND`
3. I have tried to use fuzzy search, but I have gotten a varying degree of false positives or omitted results, depending on the threshold.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [NGramFilter](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions#FilterDescriptions-N-GramFilter) to achieve this. It will split the terms into multiple tokens, where each token will be a substring of the original token.

The filter is only required when indexing (when querying, the tokens should match directly).